# Attempting a boolean in a switch with number limits of low, medium, and high

Tags: switch-statement, boolean, limit, rate

I'm trying to assign a percentage of a number to it's number limit it worked as an If/Else statement but when I tried to convert it to a boolean Switch I get a "not a statement" error

I cant tell what it is that I'm doing wrong here.

```
public static boolean taxRate(double rate)
{   
  final double LOW_LIM = 15000;
  final double LOW_RATE = 0.25;
  final double MEDIUM_LIM = 49001;
  final double MEDIUM_RATE = 0.5;
  final double HIGH_LIM = 49002;
  final double HIGH_RATE = 0.75;

  boolean taxRate;              
  switch(taxlimit)
  {
     case(LOW_LIM):
        yearlyIncome <= LOW_LIM;
        taxRate = LOW_RATE;
        break;
     case(MEDIUM_LIM):    
        yearlyIncome <= yearlyIncome >= MEDIUM_LIM && yearlyIncome < HIGH_LIM;
        taxRate = MEDIUM_RATE;
        break;
     case(HIGH_LIM):    
        yearlyIncome <= HIGH_LIM;
        taxRate = HIGH_RATE;
  }
  return taxRate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement only works with constants and only checks for equality. You can replase IF/ELSE with a SWITCH only if your IFs look like this

```
if (var == const1) .....;
else if (var == const2) ....;
else if (var == const3) ....;
else .....;
```

This

```
yearlyIncome <= yearlyIncome >= MEDIUM_LIM && yearlyIncome < HIGH_LIM;
```

is not a statement, but an expression - it does not say WHAT to do. A statement MUST say what to do.